# onclick function in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to add `onClick` event on `<a>` tag which contains `php` variables

```
$delete = "<a onclick='return confirmDelete('deleterecord.php?chkid=$sl&table=$getid&path=$validURL');'><img src='images/dustbin.png' width='43px' height='30px'></a>";  // link not pass
```

//script

```
<script>
    function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
            window.location = delUrl;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
$link = "deleterecord.php?chkid=$sl&table=$getid&path=$validURL";

and use

```
return confirmDelete(\"<?=$link?>\")
```

2.
Escape single quotes by using black slash before single quote:

```
  <img src=\'images/dustbin.png\' width=\'43px\' height=\'30px\'>
```

Comment: still not running confirmDelete ?????

Comment: Have you escaped the single quotes?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: function is not calling

Comment: put alert inside function. use double quotes around <?=link?>, it should work.

Comment: Please check the edited answer. You need to use double quotes and need to escape those double quotes.

Comment: yess done..!!! thank you very much

Comment: Welcome. Please mark this as answer

Comment: thank you. Please also up vote. It is showing as negative one.

Comment: please update the ans  right syntext is : return confirmDelete(\"$link\")

Comment: can you tell me about bar graph script in php that is connected with mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Use php's echo to return html/css/js stuff:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.echo.php

```
<?php
$delete = "
    <a onclick='confirm_(\"deleterecord.php?chkid=$sl&table=$getid&path=$validURL'\")'; class='link'>
        <img src='images/dustbin.png' width='43px' height='30px'>
    </a>";
echo($delete);
?>
<script>
function confirm_(url){
        console.log(url);
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")){
            window.location = url;
        }
}
</script>
```

*Like **Rayon Dabre** sayed, you have to escape string.*

---

**Maurize's casual/smart/lazy solution:**

You should echo a link with a path like `delete.php?action=delete&id=2`

and on php side

*`if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "delete"){ echo $_GET["id"]; }`*

***Will looks like:***

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "delete"){
    echo $_GET["id"];
}
?>
<a href="index.php?action=delete&id=1">Lazy Casual?</a>
```

or

```
<?php
echo("
<a href='deleterecord.php?chkid=$sl&table=$getid&path=$validURL'>
    <img src='images/dustbin.png' width='43px' height='30px'>
</a>
");
?>
```

*Tested and works like mexican.*

> - The masterpiece of deletion would be using AJAX + JS - **Maurize**

Comment: yes i have already echo but the link is not pass into the function due to ' ' (commass)

Comment: May I show you a smarter way?

Comment: yeah ofcrs i'm waiting  now

Comment: Now you have multiple methods you can choose from.